# Data sync between Sqlite and google calendar

Tags: android, calendar

My application has its own calendar daily saves the user-created content in the SQLite database. It turns out that I need to export / sync these same records for the Google Calendar. Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **calendar provider**. [Official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) should help in it